# Panic recovery outside a go routine

Tags: unit-testing, go, goroutine

I'm trying to unit test a function that will start a go routine and make sure this go routine panics in extreme circumstances (I pass in a mocked function that causes this). I'm not necessarily expecting this to actually occur in production but it's nice to have tests to cover this. The code is below:

```
// unit test
func TestPersistLogsPanic(t *testing.T) {
    defer func() {
        if r := recover(); r == nil {
            t.Error("Error in log saver should cause PersistLogs to panic")
        }
    }()

    go PersistLogs(hpq, lpq, mockPanicSaver)
    hpq <- Log{}
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
}

// function being tested
func PersistLogs(highPriorityChan chan Log, lowPriorityChan chan Log, saveFunc saver) {
    var nextLog Log
    for {
        if len(highPriorityChan) > 0 {
            nextLog = <-highPriorityChan
        } else {
            select {
            case nextLog = <-highPriorityChan:
            case nextLog = <-lowPriorityChan:
            }
        }
        err := saveFunc(nextLog)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}

// mock Saver function
func mockPanicSaver(_ Log) error {
    return errors.New("Test log save error")
}
```

`PersistLogs` waits for a `Log` to come though either the `hpq` or `lpq` channels, then 'saves' the `Log` using the function passed as the third param. This function populates a variable in `PersistLogs` that later causes a panic (hope that makes sense).

The issue is that the call to `recover` is outside the go routine that causes the panic. Are there any ways around this that people know of? Might be I'm doing this a strange way and others have a better idea - open to ideas!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oddly, I just commited this to vc out of habit, it ran the tests on a pipeline and passed - perhaps a race condition sneaking around somewhere...

Comment: You can't recover function panicing in another goroutine. Why do not you just call PersistLogs() in TestPersistLogsPanic() instead of spawning go routine?

Comment: That's a good point, I was trying to replicate the production conditions as closely as possible, but in this case it may make little difference.